# How can I add a linear-gradient colour to my underline for my heading?

Tags: html, css, border, gradient, underline

I have underlined part of my heading for a website I am building and can colour it normally but I'm struggling when adding a linear gradient colour to it.

I have resorted to putting the section of the heading into a span and colouring the `border-bottom` and that seems to work, however the border is too far down for it to be an underline.

The coding is this:

```css
span {
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7228fe 0%, #4ea2f5 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    float: center;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You can do it using a pseudo element

Comment: `float: center;` is not valid ... and why not show us the final result you want to obtain

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put your heading in a `div` and target the `div` using CSS.

```css
.box {
 border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7228fe  0%,#7228fe  60%, #4ea2f5 61%, #4ea2f5 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>box</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/visheshthakur/pen/XZxWwy